# Help formatting really long equations

Tags: formatting, equations

I have some really long differential equations and I'm having trouble figuring out how to format them the way I want. I want them to look liek this:
dx/dt = blah blah
        blah blah
dx/dt = blah blah
        blah blah
and so on. I'm having trouble with them not being left justified and running off the page. Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Equations}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}= - c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{1} + c_{2}*x_{3} - c_{3}*x_{25}*x_{1}\\ + c_{4}*x_{5} - c_{5}*x_{1}*x_{26} + c_{6}*x_{4} - c_{7}*x_{1}*x_{13}\\ + c_{8}*x_{12} - c_{9}*x_{1}*x_{18} + c_{10}*x_{17} - c_{11}*x_{1}*x_{24} + c_{12}*x_{23} - c_{13}*x_{1}*x_{19}\\ + c_{14}*x_{20}\
\frac{dx_{2}}{dt}= - c_{1}*x_{1}*x_{2} + c_{2}*x_{3} - c_{1}*x_{2}*(x_{4}\\ + x_{5} + x_{7} + x_{12} + x_{14} + x_{17} + x_{20} + x_{23}) - c_{15}*(x_{6}\\ + x_{8} + x_{9} + x_{11} + x_{15} + x_{16} + x_{21} + x_{22})\
\frac{dx_{3}}{dt}= - c_{16}*x_{3}*x_{26} + c_{17}*x_{6}\\ - c_{18}*x_{3}*x_{25} + c_{19}*x_{8} + c_{1}*x_{1}*x_{2} - c_{2}*x_{3} - c_{7}*x_{3}*x_{13}\\ + c_{8}*x_{11} - c_{9}*x_{3}*x_{18} + c_{10}*x_{16} - c_{11}*x_{3}*x_{24} + c_{12}*x_{22}\
\frac{dx_{4}}{dt}= c_{5}*x_{1}*x_{26} - c_{6}*x_{4} - c_{3}*x_{4}*x_{25}\\ + c_{4}*x_{7} - c_{1}*x_{4}*x_{2} + c_{15}*x_{6}\
\frac{dx_{5}}{dt}= c_{3}*x_{1}*x_{25} - c_{4}*x_{5} - c_{5}*x_{5}*x_{26}\\ + c_{6}*x_{7} - c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{5} + c_{15}*x_{8}\
\frac{dx_{6}}{dt}= c_{16}*x_{3}*x_{26} - c_{17}*x_{6} - c_{18}*x_{6}*x_{25}\\ + c_{19}*x_{9} - c_{15}*x_{6} + c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{4}\
\frac{dx_{7}}{dt}= c_{5}*x_{5}*x_{26} - c_{6}*x_{7} + c_{3}*x_{4}*x_{25}\\ - c_{4}*x_{7} - c_{1}*x_{7}*x_{2} + c_{15}*x_{9} - c_{22}*x_{7}\
\frac{dx_{8}}{dt}= c_{18}*x_{3}*x_{25} - c_{19}*x_{8} - c_{16}*x_{8}*x_{26}\\ + c_{17}*x_{9} - c_{15}*x_{8} + c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{5}\
\frac{dx_{9}}{dt}= c_{16}*x_{8}*x_{26} - c_{17}*x_{9} + c_{18}*x_{6}*x_{25}\\ - c_{19}*x_{9} + c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{7} - c_{15}*x_{9} - c_{20}*x_{9}\
\frac{dx_{10}}{dt}= (c_{20}*x_{9}*(1 - c_{23})\\ + c_{22}*x_{7}*(1 - c_{24}))*c_{25}^{c_{26}} - x_{10}\
\frac{dx_{11}}{dt}= c_{20}*c_{23}*x_{9} - c_{15}*x_{11}\\ + c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{12} - c_{13}*x_{11}*x_{19} + c_{14}*x_{15} + c_{7}*x_{3}*x_{13}\\ - c_{8}*x_{11}\
\frac{dx_{12}}{dt}= c_{22}*x_{7}*c_{24} + c_{7}*x_{1}*x_{13}\\ - c_{8}*x_{12} - c_{1}*x_{12}*x_{2} + c_{15}*x_{11} - c_{13}*x_{12}*x_{19}\\ + c_{14}*x_{14}\
\frac{dx_{13}}{dt}= - c_{7}*x_{13}*(x_{1} + x_{3} + x_{20} + x_{21})\\ + c_{8}*(x_{11} + x_{12} + x_{14} + x_{15})\
\frac{dx_{14}}{dt}= c_{13}*x_{12}*x_{19} - c_{14}*x_{14}\\ - c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{14} + c_{15}*x_{15} + c_{7}*x_{20}*x_{13} - c_{8}*x_{14}\
\frac{dx_{15}}{dt}= c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{14} - c_{15}*x_{15}\\ + c_{13}*x_{11}*x_{19} - c_{14}*x_{15} - c_{21}*x_{15} + c_{7}*x_{21}*x_{13} - c_{8}*x_{15}\
\frac{dx_{16}}{dt}= c_{20}*(1 - c_{23})*x_{9} - c_{15}*x_{16}\\ + c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{17} + c_{9}*x_{3}*x_{18} - c_{10}*x_{16}\
\frac{dx_{17}}{dt}= c_{22}*(1 - c_{24})*x_{7} + c_{15}*x_{16}\\ - c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{17} + c_{9}*x_{1}*x_{18} - c_{10}*x_{17}\
\frac{dx_{18}}{dt}= - c_{9}*x_{18}*(x_{1} + x_{3})\\ + c_{10}*(x_{17} + x_{16})\
\frac{dx_{19}}{dt}= c_{20}*(1 - c_{23})*x_{9}\\ - c_{13}*x_{19}*(x_{12} + x_{1}) + c_{14}*(x_{14} + x_{20}) + c_{22}*(1 - c_{24})*x_{7}\
\frac{dx_{20}}{dt}= c_{13}*x_{1}*x_{19} - c_{14}*x_{20}\\ - c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{20} + c_{15}*x_{21} - c_{7}*x_{20}*x_{13} + c_{8}*x_{14}\
\frac{dx_{21}}{dt}= c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{20} - c_{15}*x_{21}\\ - c_{7}*x_{21}*x_{13} + x_{8}*x_{15}\
\frac{dx_{22}}{dt}= c_{21}*x_{15} - c_{15}*x_{22} + c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{23}\\ + c_{11}*x_{3}*x_{24} - c_{12}*x_{22}\
\frac{dx_{23}}{dt}= c_{11}*x_{1}*x_{24} - c_{12}*x_{23}\\ - c_{1}*x_{2}*x_{23} + c_{15}*x_{22}\
\frac{dx_{24}}{dt}= - c_{11}*x_{24}*(x_{1} + x_{3})\\ + c_{12}*(x_{23} + x_{22})\
\frac{dx_{25}}{dt}= - c_{3}*x_{25}*(x_{1} + x_{4})\\ + c_{4}*(x_{5} + x_{7}) - c_{18}*x_{25}*(x_{3} + x_{6}) + c_{19}*(x_{8} + x_{9})\
\frac{dx_{26}}{dt}= - c_{5}*x_{26}*(x_{1} + x_{5})\\ + c_{6}*(x_{4} + x_{7}) - c_{16}*x_{26}*(x_{3} + x_{8}) + c_{17}*(x_{6} + x_{9})\
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{multline}
\maketitle
\raggedright
\[`  multline is a display math environment so it can not contain `\maketitle` or `\raggedright` or `\[`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please make your document compilable.

Comment: "fixed errors?" not really: cut and paste the code from the question and try it locally. You need `\\ ` not `\ ` at the end of each line for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please test your code before posting.

If I remove the obvious errors such as starting math mode with `\[` inside the `multline` math environment then it mostly fitted on a page except for the first three long equations. iused `gathered` here for those, but `split` or `aligned` are alternatives. I also used `align` for the main list rather than `multline` and used juxtaposition rather than `*` for multiplication.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Equations}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}&= \begin{gathered}- c_{1}x_{2}x_{1} + c_{2}x_{3} - c_{3}x_{25}x_{1} + c_{4}x_{5} - c_{5}x_{1}x_{26} + c_{6}x_{4}  - c_{7}x_{1}x_{13}\\
 + c_{8}x_{12} - c_{9}x_{1}x_{18} + c_{10}x_{17} - c_{11}x_{1}x_{24} + c_{12}x_{23} - c_{13}x_{1}x_{19} + c_{14}x_{20}\end{gathered}\\
\frac{dx_{2}}{dt}&= \begin{gathered}-- c_{1}x_{1}x_{2} + c_{2}x_{3} - c_{1}x_{2}(x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{7} + x_{12} + x_{14} + x_{17}\\
 + x_{20} + x_{23}) - c_{15}(x_{6} + x_{8} + x_{9} + x_{11} + x_{15} + x_{16} + x_{21} + x_{22})\end{gathered}\\
\frac{dx_{3}}{dt}&=\begin{gathered} - c_{16}x_{3}x_{26} + c_{17}x_{6} - c_{18}x_{3}x_{25} + c_{19}x_{8} + c_{1}x_{1}x_{2} - c_{2}x_{3}\\
 - c_{7}x_{3}x_{13} + c_{8}x_{11} - c_{9}x_{3}x_{18} + c_{10}x_{16} - c_{11}x_{3}x_{24} + c_{12}x_{22}\end{gathered}\\
\frac{dx_{4}}{dt}&= c_{5}x_{1}x_{26} - c_{6}x_{4} - c_{3}x_{4}x_{25} + c_{4}x_{7} - c_{1}x_{4}x_{2} + c_{15}x_{6}\\
\frac{dx_{5}}{dt}&= c_{3}x_{1}x_{25} - c_{4}x_{5} - c_{5}x_{5}x_{26} + c_{6}x_{7} - c_{1}x_{2}x_{5} + c_{15}x_{8}\\
\frac{dx_{6}}{dt}&= c_{16}x_{3}x_{26} - c_{17}x_{6} - c_{18}x_{6}x_{25} + c_{19}x_{9} - c_{15}x_{6} + c_{1}x_{2}x_{4}\\
\frac{dx_{7}}{dt}&= c_{5}x_{5}x_{26} - c_{6}x_{7} + c_{3}x_{4}x_{25} - c_{4}x_{7} - c_{1}x_{7}x_{2} + c_{15}x_{9} - c_{22}x_{7}\\
\frac{dx_{8}}{dt}&= c_{18}x_{3}x_{25} - c_{19}x_{8} - c_{16}x_{8}x_{26} + c_{17}x_{9} - c_{15}x_{8} + c_{1}x_{2}x_{5}\\
\frac{dx_{9}}{dt}&= c_{16}x_{8}x_{26} - c_{17}x_{9} + c_{18}x_{6}x_{25} - c_{19}x_{9} + c_{1}x_{2}x_{7} - c_{15}x_{9} - c_{20}x_{9}\\
\frac{dx_{10}}{dt}&= (c_{20}x_{9}(1 - c_{23}) + c_{22}x_{7}(1 - c_{24}))c_{25}c_{26} - x_{10}\\
\frac{dx_{11}}{dt}&= c_{20}c_{23}x_{9} - c_{15}x_{11} + c_{1}x_{2}x_{12} - c_{13}x_{11}x_{19} + c_{14}x_{15} + c_{7}x_{3}x_{13} - c_{8}x_{11}\\
\frac{dx_{12}}{dt}&= c_{22}x_{7}c_{24} + c_{7}x_{1}x_{13} - c_{8}x_{12} - c_{1}x_{12}x_{2} + c_{15}x_{11} - c_{13}x_{12}x_{19} + c_{14}x_{14}\\
\frac{dx_{13}}{dt}&= - c_{7}x_{13}(x_{1} + x_{3} + x_{20} + x_{21}) + c_{8}(x_{11} + x_{12} + x_{14} + x_{15})\\
\frac{dx_{14}}{dt}&= c_{13}x_{12}x_{19} - c_{14}x_{14} - c_{1}x_{2}x_{14} + c_{15}x_{15} + c_{7}x_{20}x_{13} - c_{8}x_{14}\\
\frac{dx_{15}}{dt}&= c_{1}x_{2}x_{14} - c_{15}x_{15} + c_{13}x_{11}x_{19} - c_{14}x_{15} - c_{21}x_{15} + c_{7}x_{21}x_{13} - c_{8}x_{15}\\
\frac{dx_{16}}{dt}&= c_{20}(1 - c_{23})x_{9} - c_{15}x_{16} + c_{1}x_{2}x_{17} + c_{9}x_{3}x_{18} - c_{10}x_{16}\\
\frac{dx_{17}}{dt}&= c_{22}(1 - c_{24})x_{7} + c_{15}x_{16} - c_{1}x_{2}x_{17} + c_{9}x_{1}x_{18} - c_{10}x_{17}\\
\frac{dx_{18}}{dt}&= - c_{9}x_{18}(x_{1} + x_{3}) + c_{10}(x_{17} + x_{16})\\
\frac{dx_{19}}{dt}&= c_{20}(1 - c_{23})x_{9} - c_{13}x_{19}(x_{12} + x_{1}) + c_{14}(x_{14} + x_{20}) + c_{22}(1 - c_{24})x_{7}\\
\frac{dx_{20}}{dt}&= c_{13}x_{1}x_{19} - c_{14}x_{20} - c_{1}x_{2}x_{20} + c_{15}x_{21} - c_{7}x_{20}x_{13} + c_{8}x_{14}\\
\frac{dx_{21}}{dt}&= c_{1}x_{2}x_{20} - c_{15}x_{21} - c_{7}x_{21}x_{13} + x_{8}x_{15}\\
\frac{dx_{22}}{dt}&= c_{21}x_{15} - c_{15}x_{22} + c_{1}x_{2}x_{23} + c_{11}x_{3}x_{24} - c_{12}x_{22}\\
\frac{dx_{23}}{dt}&= c_{11}x_{1}x_{24} - c_{12}x_{23} - c_{1}x_{2}x_{23} + c_{15}x_{22}\\
\frac{dx_{24}}{dt}&= - c_{11}x_{24}(x_{1} + x_{3}) + c_{12}(x_{23} + x_{22})\\
\frac{dx_{25}}{dt}&= - c_{3}x_{25}(x_{1} + x_{4}) + c_{4}(x_{5} + x_{7}) - c_{18}x_{25}(x_{3} + x_{6}) + c_{19}(x_{8} + x_{9})\\
\frac{dx_{26}}{dt}&= - c_{5}x_{26}(x_{1} + x_{5}) + c_{6}(x_{4} + x_{7}) - c_{16}x_{26}(x_{3} + x_{8}) + c_{17}(x_{6} + x_{9})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't even realize those were errors.

Comment: @rdale1 LaTeX must have screamed multiple error messages. Do not ignore them! If tex makes an error message the typeset result is essentially arbitrary TeX recovers to try to let processing carry on to find more errors, it does not try to generate reasonable pdf after an error.